# Kafka streams and large messages

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

We have to process with Kafka streams, along with a vast majority of small messages, a very few number of messages exceeding the size limit of the broker.

Increasing broker limit is not an option, as well as chunking for such big messages. What would be a best strategy to handle such messages?

It appeared to be at least a working approach to catch `RecordTooLargeException` in a custom implementation of `ProductionExceptionHandler`, to send gzipped message then. But I wonder if there could be a better / more elegant way to deal with that?

Comment: Sharing this as inspiration. SQS from AWS has a feature in which large messages are stored in S3 and only the url of the 'payload' is sent on the message. I'm not sure if there's a library that would do this for you, but it shouldn't be too difficult to build one. You could also use a different approach to S3 (e.g. store it in a shared network drive, etc). For reference these are the [docs from SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-s3-messages.html) on this topic.

Comment: I concur with the first comment, for the large payloads it is considered the best practice to store the content to an object storage of your favorite service/cloud provider and pass the reference in the message

Comment: Yeah, the idea of externalizing the payload is rather obvious, but not an option in this particular case.